# Function to rewrite URl in Wordpress

Tags: url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrte this URL `http://example.com/news/?news_id=2` to `http://example.com/news/2` where news is the page and 2 is the `news_id`

**I have added following code in functions.php:**

```
function add_news_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%news_id%", '([^/]*)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^news/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=news&news_id=$matches[1]','top');    
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_news_rewrite_rule' );

function my_insert_query_vars( $vars ){
    array_push($vars, 'news_id');
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars','my_insert_query_vars' );
```

And I am using **`$wp_query->query_vars['news_id']`** instead of **`$_GET['news_id']`** to pull out the data from database.

But this is not working. Please help me.

Comment: Use `get_query_var()` instead of directly accessing `$wp_query->query_vars['news_id']`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Permalink settings in the admin, you should be able to achieve what you want there. Here is a link to the [Permalink Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

something like `/%post_id%` should do the job, if you select the 'Custom Structure' option.